# angularJS ng-options how to get text from select option [NOT VALUE]

Tags: angularjs

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RD2Bz/4/)

I am trying to get selected TEXT from drop down selection box.

I am using `ng-options="region.code as region.name for region in regions"` with `region.code` and `region.name`

I Googled it and find many issues related to ng-options but could not able to find above.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

Bind the entire region to your variable on scope,e.g:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-options="region as region.name for region in regions" ng-model="region">
  <option style="display:none" value="">select a region</option>
  </select>
  <br>selected: {{region.name}}
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.regions = [
    ....
    ];

    $scope.region = $scope.regions[0];
    ....
}
```

Here's an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RD2Bz/5/): http://jsfiddle.net/RD2Bz/5/

Comment: But I am online getting Code (ID - foreign key - i.e AL, AS, AK)  from database. not $scope.regions[0]

Comment: So what's the problem? You get code from database, once you have that find the region in your array and assign it to $scope.region

Comment: I am looking some straight solution rather than looping through long array to find entry. my code works fine to select entry from dropdown by ID(Code) but it does not work to get Text for that specific selected entry.

Comment: You will have to lookup somewhere a long the line to get the name from the ID.

Comment: @Developer, there's no way you can avoid looping through array with such data structure. Maybe you could create some sort of index where state code is the key and name and other stuff is the value like `{'AK': {name: 'Alaska'} }`. This will allow you to avoid looping